# LaTeX between dollar signs does not work in editing answer

Tags: bug, mathjax, editing, answers

I tried to edit this answer: [Steve Awodey "Category Theory" - possible error](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526301/steve-awodey-category-theory-possible-error/526343#526343)

After clicking "Edit" button I went to https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/526343/edit

In preview I see dollar signs and LaTeX between them, but no rendered formulas! It is a bug.

Comment: It seems to render correctly at an update, for example after inputing another character.